# Compare two DIVs and highlight the unmatched content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare the text of first div content with second div content which consists of images in the div and wants to highlight the unmatched text of the second div.

below is the HTML div I have.

```html
<!-- div #1 -->
<div class="col-lg-12" id="oldversion">
  <p>this is an article one!!! Harsha</p>
  <p><br><img src="sample.jpg" style="max-width: 100% !important;max-height: 100% !important;" "width:=" " 867px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib"></p>
  <p>Hello world..</p>
  <p><br></p>
  <p><br><img src="sample1.jpg" style="max-width: 100% !important;max-height: 100% !important;" "width:=" " 737px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib"></p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- div #2 -->
<div class="col-lg-12" id="newVersion">
  <p>this is an article two !!!</p>
  <p><br><img src="sample.jpg" style="max-width: 100% !important;max-height: 100% !important;" "width:=" " 867px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib"></p>
  <p>Hello world.. Naveen</p>
  <p><br></p>
  <p><br><img src="sample1.jpg" style="max-width: 100% !important;max-height: 100% !important;" "width:=" " 737px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib"></p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<div id="compared">


</div>

<div class="form-bottom">
            <button type="button" id="revert" onClick="articleHighlight();"class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i> Compare
            </button>
        </div>
```

This is what I tried so far but it is comparing only text it's not showing the images:

```
function articleHighlight() {
    var newText = $("#newVersion");
    var oldText = $("#oldversion");
    var text = "";
    try{
          newText.text().split("").forEach(function(value, index) {
          if (value != oldText.text().charAt(index))
             text += "<span class='highlight text-danger'>" + value + "</span>";
          else
             text += value;
      });
}
catch (ex){
         alert("exception");
   }
       $("#compared").html(text);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amhLbq52/100/)

Comment: `.text()` will return only the text content of the element. I think you should try with `.contents()` which returns text and children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to compare the `innerHTML` instead of the `innerText`:

```
var newText = newVersion.html();
var oldText = oldVersion.html();
```

Don't get the `.text()`/`.html()` twice, reuse it:

```
newText.split("").forEach(function(value, index) {
    //your code
});
```

and instead of putting each character into separate `span`s, you should simply store intervals of indexes, so you will know where matches are starting and when they are ending. Also, you will need to wrap `span`s around matches as well and make sure you create such tags and set their `innerText` instead of their `innerHTML`, so you will see each character instead of html tags.

Comment: I tried the process you gave, but it is not highlighting the text. It is showing the whole div content as it is.

Comment: this is what i tried `var newText = newVersion.html();
        var oldText = oldVersion.html();
        var text = "";
        newText.text().split("").forEach(function(value, index) {
            if (value != oldText.charAt(index))
                text += "<span class='highlight text-danger'>" + value + "</span>";
            else
                text += value;
        });
        newVersion.html(text);`

Comment: @Naveen you did not apply my proposal. My proposal included finding the intervals where those are different and where those are the same, including each interval into a wrapper tag, the creation of a tag and defining its html instead of  text += "<span class='highlight text-danger'>" + value + "</span>"; else text += value; among others.

Comment: can you please let me know how to get the intervals and applying span to them ?

Comment: @Naveen you create an array of objects. Each object in the array will contain a start and an end field, denoting the starting end ending indexes of the intervals, along with another field, which will be boolean to denote whether the interval is a match or a difference. At the very first index you create a new interval, regardless of whether it was a match or not. At later indexes you will take into account the match boolean value of the last open interval and compare its logical value to the comparison to determine whether it is a match. If the values match, do nothing to the interval.

Comment: @Naveen if they do not match, then you store the ending index of the previous interval and add a new interval to the array, knowing its starting index and its match logical value. When you finish the cycle, you close the last interval by storing the last possible index as the end of the last interval object. Then you do another cycle, which goes through the interval array and creates a tag object for each interval, a span with the corresponding classes and call the .html() function of the jquery object and pass the text, or set the innerText of the tag object to the interval.

Comment: @Naveen to do so, you will need to take the text's substring from the starting interval and end - start as the length.

Comment: i am storing the new text in one array and old text in another array, ` var newVersionTags=$(newVersion).find('p'); var newText=[]; $.each(newVersionTags,function(index,element){ if(element.textContent!=="") { newText.push(element.textContent); } }); var oldVersionTags=$(oldVersion).find('p'); var oldText=[]; $.each(oldVersionTags,function(index,element){ if(element.textContent!=="") { oldText.push(element.textContent); } }); `